# how to insert between for a string date query

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL and I'm trying to figure out where to put a between to run dates for 4Q 2016.

I've tried a 'between' in place of 'and' also the '>=' '<='

```
and (STR_TO_DATE(week_of, '%m/%d/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('09/26/2016','%m/%d/%Y') 
and STR_TO_DATE(week_of, '%m/%d/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('12/25/2016','%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on how did `BETWEEN... AND..` comparison didn't work? That would be my recommendation

Comment: I replace the AND with BETWEEN which gave me an error when I ran the query.

Then I tried BETWEEN in place of >= and <=, got another error.

Comment: that could be due to other factors, probably is better if you put your full query

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use this form 
DATE >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') AND DATE <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')

Answer (score 0):

The `BETWEEN` syntax is simple.
It just needs an `AND`.

```
 STR_TO_DATE(week_of, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('09/26/2016','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('12/25/2016','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Or simplified:

```
 STR_TO_DATE(week_of, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN DATE('2016-09-26') AND DATE('2016-12-25')
```